# ¿Còmo dar una respuesta en Tkinter/python según el resultado le de un mensaje al usuario?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy aprendiendo a programar y quería hacer un programa sencillo que le pregunte al usuario su salario. En caso de ser la cifra ingresada menor a 200000000 que obtenga "no pagaràs... " y en caso de ser mayor, que le devuelva "te tocará pagar...", pero ya me perdì.

```
import tkinter as tk

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300,  relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text="¿Pagaré grandes fortunas?")
label1.config(font=('helvetica', 14))
canvas1.create_window(200, 25, window=label1)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text="¿De cuánto es tu sueldo?")
label2.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
canvas1.create_window(200, 100, window=label2)

boton1 = tk.Button(root, 
text ="Descubre si pagarás impuesto a las grandes fortunas")
boton1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)

def respuestaSueldo ():
    respuestaSueldo = entry1.get()


from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def ShowMsg():
    messagebox.showinfo("No pagarás impuesto a las grandes fortunas")
ventana3 = tk.Tk()
ventana3.geometry("400x150")
ventana3.title("Resultado")

boton2 = Button(ventana3, text= "submit", command=ShowMsg)

def rsp():
    rsp2=entry1.get
    if resp2 < 200
```

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo de su pregunta lo que intenta hacer es mostrar el evento o la respuesta que se genera cuando usted ingresa un valor en una entrada de texto o Entry dependiendo del valor establecido.

- Si es así en este caso hay varias cosas que faltan en su código es el
  rango entre `200000000` y el valor máximo que por ahora es
  independiente, no hay valor máximo según el contexto de su pregunta.
- Lo que debería hacer es agregar una validación y un rango o en otras
  palabras validar el texto ingresado en el Entry.
- Hay un uso no correcto de los módulos, los módulos que vaya a
  utilizar procure ponerlos siempre al inicio del código no al utilizar una
  función o definir un objeto después.
- No estableció el fin del ciclo de eventos o `mainloop()` algo que es
  muy importante a la hora de publicar su código para ejecutar o
  probarlo.
- Porque utiliza el widget Canvas no es necesario. El código está
  incompleto y poco organizado.

Una solución más elegante o propia para lo que intenta hacer sería lo siguiente:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox # importar módulo de messagebox.

#Autor John Deb, código modificable. 24/02/21, nombre común the gamer :v

root= tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x260')
root.geometry('+360+20')
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title('Comprobar salario')

# Definir los widgets del programa como labels, controles entre otros...

labelTitle = tk.Label(root, text="¿Pagaré grandes fortunas?", font=('Microsoft Sans Serif',14, 'bold'))
labelTitle.place(x=60, y=30)

Separator=ttk.Separator(root, orient='horizontal')
Separator.place(x=14, y=87, width = 368)

labelEntryInfo = tk.Label(root, text="¿De cuánto es su sueldo?                                          \nDescubra si pagará impuesto a las grandes fortunas", font=('Microsoft Sans Serif',8))
labelEntryInfo.place(x=10, y=100)

labelEntryInfo2 = tk.Label(root, text="Ingrese el valor numérico de su sueldo actual:", font=('Microsoft Sans Serif',8))
labelEntryInfo2.place(x=10, y=150)

def SoloNumero2(char):
    return char.isdigit() # Validar solo numeros, no deja escribir letras u otro carácter que no sea un número entero en el Entry.   

def limit_text2(*args): # Función de limitar texto en el widget de Entry
    value = ValueVar.get()
    if len(value) > 15: ValueVar.set(value[:15]) # 15 caracteres máximo puse actualmente puede cambiarse el valor si uno quiere.

def GetValuesRange(): # Función primaria para actualizar el estado del botón de 'Descubrir'
    try: 
        valor = int(EntryValue.get()) # Verificar el valor ingresado si es entero
                   
        if (valor<=0): # Si es menor
            #Valores deben estar entre el intervalo especificado.
            ValidarEntry.config(state='disabled')


                      
        elif (valor>=199999999): # Si es mayor
            #Valores deben estar entre el intervalo especificado.
            ValidarEntry.config(state='normal')


        else:                   
            ValidarEntry.config(state='normal') # Si no hay información, o no son valores válidos

    except ValueError:   
        ValidarEntry.config(state='disabled') # Deshabilitar si no es válido el valor ingresado       

    root.after(100, GetValuesRange) # Actualizar cada cierto tiempo la función.

            
validation2 = (root.register(SoloNumero2)) # Registrar y validar el valor
ValueVar = tk.StringVar() 
ValueVar.trace("w", limit_text2) # Limitar texto mediante la función.
EntryValue =ttk.Entry(root ,font=("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8), textvariable=ValueVar, takefocus=False, validatecommand=(validation2, '%S'), validate='all') # Entrada de texto de valores.
EntryValue.place(x=13,y=175, height=24, width=369)
EntryValue.focus_set()

ButtonStyle = ttk.Style() 
ButtonStyle.configure('TButton', font =('Microsoft Sans Serif', 8)) # Estilo de los botones.

def GetValuesRange2(): # Validar valor del entry
    try: 
        valor = int(EntryValue.get()) # Verificar el valor ingresado si es entero
                   
        if (valor<=199999999): # Si es menor
            #Valores deben estar entre el intervalo especificado.
            #Retornar en los messagbox mediante el string (str) del título
            messagebox.showinfo(str(root.title()), "No pagarás impuesto a las grandes fortunas")


                      
        elif (valor>=199999999): # Si es mayor 
            #Valores deben estar entre el intervalo especificado.
            #Retornar en los messagbox mediante el string (str) del título
            messagebox.showinfo(str(root.title()), "Te tocará pagar...")


        else:                   
            messagebox.showwarning("Advertencia", "El valor escrito debe ser numérico y entero.") # Si no hay información, o no son valores válidos 

    except ValueError:   
        messagebox.showwarning("Advertencia", "El valor escrito debe ser numérico y entero.") # Deshabilitar si no es válido el valor ingresado        



ValidarEntry  = ttk.Button(root, text='Descubir', takefocus=False, style='TButton', width=13, command=GetValuesRange2) # Ejecuta el comando de validación de rango de valores.)    
ValidarEntry.place(x=210, y=209) 

GetValuesRange() #Carga la función de validación, si no hay valores menores a 0, estará deshabilitado el botón.

CloseBtn  = ttk.Button(root, text='Cerrar', takefocus=False, style='TButton', command=root.destroy) # Botón para cerrar el programa   
CloseBtn.place(x=307, y=209)

root.mainloop() # Fin ciclo de eventos del programa
```

El resultado sería el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]